# Execute node without installing

Tags: node.js, batch-file, electron, node-modules, node-webkit

I have one .JS File, which is using node_modules and doing my things. I would like to Create a Batch file or something which will run that file without node_module installation or Node installation in the Client system.
I don't want to create .exe as a client system will not allow installing 3rd party software.
Anyway, to run my code in client system without install node_module and Node in client system?

Comment: An executable file is not necessarily something that installs! Can you clarify exactly what isn't allowed to run on the client system?

Comment: This makes no sense.  You can't run a node app without either first installing node.exe or a bundled .exe (that includes node and your code).  You need an .EXE to run something!  You don't necessarily have to run an installer, but you will have to at least get a bundled exe onto the computer or onto some drive that you can access and execute it from on that computer.  This is the basics of running a program.  A batch file can run itself without installing an exe, but it can't run a node program without first having node available on that system.

Comment: Like electron or NW.js Allows executing without installing Node in the client system.

Comment: I actually also have the same dilemma!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is requiring modules from node_modules, you cannot run the file without errors, since the node_modules folder does not exist, and the modules no longer exists.

Comment: Like electron or NW.js Allows executing without installing Node in the client system.
My requirement is I take my code with node_modules or anything that required, But in the client system, I just want to execute my code. Without installing anything in his system.